# How do you access your images folder from a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, prawn

I'm setting up Prawn right now and for one param it wants to know the img location.

In their case they wrote :

```
img = "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/images/card_cutout.jpg"
```

But that points to a local gems folder. How can I make this from the controller point to `card_cutout.jpg` in my public/images/ folder.

I tried using an absolute link thinking it would work like a website but I was wrong :

```
img = "http://www.website.com/images/card_cutout.jpg
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
img = "#{Rails.root/public/images/card_cutout.jpg}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img = "#{Rails.root}/public/images/card_cutout.jpg"
```

Comment: @Coatless Interestingly... it's not an *exact* duplicate - take a look at the position of the closing brace. I'm not a ruby/rails programmer, so I can't comment  on the validity of such syntax (and the original answer, posted over 6 years ago, was upvoted and accepted), but still...

Comment: @DavidMakogon Good point. On further exploration, it appears as if the first answer was incorrect. See: https://joneslee85.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/the-dilemma-of-rails-root-vs-rails_root-complex/ (A ruby developer should pipe in as this post was flagged for low-quality.)